# Convert byte[] to PDF file without saving in local disk in Java

Tags: java, pdf

I am taking byte array as input and it should convert to PDF type file without writing into local system and this is my code:

```java
public File convertToFile(byte[] data) throws IOException, NullPointerException {
        
        FileOutputStream bar = null;
        String pathname = "filename.pdf";
        File file = new File(pathname);
        try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length)) {
            bar = new FileOutputStream(file);
            int c = 0;
            while (c < bais.read()) {
                baos.write(data);
                baos.writeTo(bar);``
                baos.flush();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return file;
    }
```

When I run this code it is returning my local path.

Comment: Can you show some sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: Are you using the rest controller of spring boot?

Comment: What is the result your are expecting ? an URL ? If you return a file, a file will be written on your local disk. If you want to return a pdf as stream, then you can use your byte array to return it to your client (like a client browser)

Comment: If you need a `File` object to point to the result, then you won't get around having to write it to *some* storage (you could "cheat" by writing it to remote storage via a network share, but I guess that's equivally pointless). In other words: the "I need a `File` return value" requirement is incompatible with "but I don't want to write it anywhere" requirement.

Comment: I am Using rest controller of spring boot and I need to return file for giving preview for the user

Comment: You write to the local disk (bar) and use the file (pathname) as the return value. Everything is correct. If you want to return something to a client you should return a byte array and on the client site you can work with it.

Comment: @kotteshiva: if your only aim is returning the body (and file name) to the client, then you shouldn't necessarily require a `File` object (and thus don't need to write to disk). Simply return a `byte[]` and add the necessary annotations to indicate the mime type.